# ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING on Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm getting an error when installing features on Server 2016 of ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING. Normally it seems to be to do with language but I can't see any missing language packs. I've read the CBS.log and not sure if I'm missing anything.

Our CBS Log is here:
http://www.filedropper.com/cbslog

Comment: "hen installing features on Server 2016" - Which features?  What errors are you getting other than those associated with your WinSxS store?

Comment: It's trying to install the Bitlocker feature. The only error is 'The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows installer fails to update itself with error 0x80073701 ERROR\_SXS\_ASSEMBLY\_MISSING and will not load any other updates](https://superuser.com/questions/857222/windows-installer-fails-to-update-itself-with-error-0x80073701-error-sxs-assembl)